# Populate a Spark List control in Flex 4 using plain text files?

Tags: list, controls, flex4, flash-builder, populate

How do I populate the Spark List control using onlt plain text files?
E.g., **http://www.mysite.com/mylist.txt** should populate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in your text file?

You have to load your text file (with HTTPService or URLLoader) and parse it into a consumable format (IList).

Comment: But how do I do that? I was hoping that populating the List control is as easy as passing the contents of a text file with multiple lines in it.

Comment: Well it's better to have some kind of structured data. Or if you don't want to modify your text file, you will need to split manually each lines and put them in an array used as a dataProvider in your List

Comment: So there's no straight-through way of doing it?